# React / Генерация изменяемых input

Tags: reactjs

Я получаю массив строк, например let arr = [123, 123, 444, т.д.] который записываю в state.

```
const [example, setExample] = useState([]);

setExample(arr)
```

Далее я вывожу свой input на каждый элемент массива.

```
{example.map(value =>

        <input key={value}
               type='text'
               className='input'
               name={value}
               value={value}
               onChange={handleChangeExample(value)}/>
        )}
```

Но при таком выводе поля input получаются неизменяемые. Обычно изменяемый value у input делается через свой state в value, но тут input может быть разное кол-во, с разными изначальными значениями.

Сам обработчик:

```
const handleChangeExample = name => event => {          
     event.persist();         
     setExample2(st => ({...st, [name]:  event.target.value}))};
```

setExample2 тут собирает значения всех инпутов в формате name:value.
(общий обработчик на все input)

Может я изначально что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Что вам мешает input превратить в компонент, в котором будет state для хранения value? Про неизменяемые инпуты читайте документацию по формам https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Смысл понятен, спасибо! Но теперь есть проблема, как правильно повесить обработчик, чтобы контролировать изменения. Сам обработчик добавил в вопрос.

Comment: У вас есть родитель, в котором есть состояние и метод изменения своего состояния. Вам надо метод родителя передать до компонентов потомков, это можно сделать пропсами. Читайте про подъем состояний https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html